# How can I make Linux Kernel intermediate file (.i) for different arch?

Tags: linux, architecture, kernel, intermediate-code

I'm trying to run the command on x86_64, for Linux 3.10:

```
$ make drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom/bcm63xx_enet.i
```

The problem is that this file is to be built on MPIS arch that is different from my own. How can I configure my build environment so I can generate the intermediate file for that specific c file?

Comment: You need to configure a MIPS kernel using a cross-compiler.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, but it is only a matter of using the correct compiler include flags and config options. As I do not want to generate binaries, is this really needed? Aren't there better options other than cross compiling tools?

Comment: You need a MIPS cross-compiler because some things are particular to MIPS... (e.g. some compiler specific headers like `<limits.h>`, some GCC builtins, etc...)

Comment: You should explain **why** you want to get this particular `bcm63xx_enet.i` file....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, for checking if the preprocessor complains or not when on that file. I'm not interested in that file only, I'm interested in the way of doing it.